# Build multiple apps with same core

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I have few separate apps that have absolute same logic and functions but have different icons and some design elements. The problem is that when some changes to logic and functions are made - I need to manually add this functionality to all apps and after this - I need to resubmit each app.

Maybe there is some way to separate all logic so I need to change it only in one place, and all my apps would get it?

Comment: How is your project setup at the moment? Or you have different projects for each?

Comment: If there is a backend in your app. You can take the control of the enter system from your server side by writing some wrapper in your ios app side. Required more work in server side actually.

Comment: Right now there are different projects with same server API.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the neatest solution is to have one codebase with multiple targets. Yes you still have to resubmit each app when you change some code, but you would have to do that anyway would you not?

You can pick one of your apps to convert to your 'main' codebase.

E.g. Pick app one and duplicate the target multiple times:

[image]

You will want to change your scheme names after doing this:

[image]

[image]

You can set the bundle identifier and deployment info separately for each app just as you did before, and icon sets:

[image]

To differentiate between your apps in code you can use compiler flags (Target -> Build settings - Other swift flags) :

[image]

You can then do something like this in your code:

```
#if APP_ONE
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution (though not necessarily the best) is to have a single code base. I.e. you have only one physical copy of each of your classes. All your code files are located in a folder of one of the projects and the other projects use those files as well. It's just a matter of setting paths.
In this structure when you change or add some code in one of the projects (and doesn't really matter which one), all the projects are updated.
The image catalogs are different for each project.
The disadvantages of this approach are that you still need to build and submit each app separately and when adding a new class you need manually to add it to all the projects. Otherwise they won't compile.
The advantages are that when building an app, you build only one app and not all together (less time). It's also easy to manage changes to a specific app - you can just add some extension with additional functionality to only one project - the rest won't need it.

Comment: It's not a good approach, Paths could be different on different system, for example i have change my system or my colleague also working on same projects we have to set paths all time we change environment. good approach from this, you can add different targets in same project for same codebase